# Is there any single verse in Chumash that contains all 22 letters of the aleph-beis?

Tags: aleph-bet-letters

Is there any single verse in Chumash that contains all 22 letters of the aleph-beis?

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/44887/759

Comment: Thanks for that. Perhaps this comment should go there, but I noticed that there is no שׂ (sin) in that possuk, only שׁ (shins). This is perhaps a topic of discussion itself - whether they can be regarded as two independent letters, but on the side that they are, would be that some words, when spelled with these have completely unrelated meanings, ex. שׂם (he placed) Vs. שׁם (there).

Comment: @ShadyChareidi if you want to count  שׂ  and  שׁ  separately, then you will have a lot more than 22 letters in your aleph-beis.

Comment: Not necessarily. In any given word, interchanging beis with veis, or pey with fey, or kaf with chaf etc will never dramatically change the core meaning of the word. But Shin with sin can result in such a categorical change.

Comment: שׂ Is more a version of ס than of שׁ. See https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/4286

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Shemos 16:16

זֶ֤ה הַדָּבָר֙ אֲשֶׁ֣ר צִוָּ֣ה יְהֹוָ֔ה לִקְט֣וּ מִמֶּ֔נּוּ אִ֖ישׁ לְפִ֣י אָכְל֑וֹ עֹ֣מֶר לַגֻּלְגֹּ֗לֶת מִסְפַּר֙ נַפְשֹׁ֣תֵיכֶ֔ם אִ֛ישׁ לַֽאֲשֶׁ֥ר בְּאָֽהֳל֖וֹ תִּקָּֽחוּ

Devarim 4:34

א֣וֹ | הֲנִסָּ֣ה אֱלֹהִ֗ים לָ֠ב֠וֹא לָקַ֨חַת ל֣וֹ גוֹי֘ מִקֶּ֣רֶב גּוֹי֒ בְּמַסֹּת֩ בְּאֹתֹ֨ת וּבְמֽוֹפְתִ֜ים וּבְמִלְחָמָ֗ה וּבְיָ֤ד חֲזָקָה֙ וּבִזְר֣וֹעַ נְטוּיָ֔ה וּבְמֽוֹרָאִ֖ים גְּדֹלִ֑ים כְּ֠כֹ֠ל אֲשֶׁר־עָשָׂ֨ה לָכֶ֜ם יְהֹוָ֧ה אֱלֹֽהֵיכֶ֛ם בְּמִצְרַ֖יִם לְעֵינֶֽיךָ

Here is a link for other places in Nach. https://www.biu.ac.il/jh/parasha/veethcha/mer.html

Comment: Thank you. How did you find that?